# After reinstalled OS I do "git add .", git adds all project's files which were committed before reinstallation. How to correct synchronization?

Tags: git

1. I have a `.git` folder that lives in my project's folder.
2. I worked on a project, did commits.
3. Then I made few new code changes and did not commmit them.
4. Reinstalled Ubuntu

---

1. Now I want to know, what code changes I made which are not commited.
2. I wanted `git add .` and then `git status` in order to see what files are different,
3. but once I did `git add .`, `git` decided to add all project's files.
4. Did a step back -> `git reset`
5. Then I tried `git pull` in order to get notification that some local changes can be lost, but as a result I saw `Already up-to-date.`

---

1. Why `git` does not see that project was added\committed before reinstallation of OS, and as a result, does not add just those files which were not committed before OS reinstallation?
2. How to find what files have a difference in comparing to the the local branch (`.git` folder)?

Comment: Was your `.git` folder someone changed during the reinstallation?

Comment: No. `.git` folder 100% did not see any changes during the reinstallation. Before the reinstallation, all projects (`/home/username/www` folder with all projects) were copied to external HDD, then returned back to the `/home/username/www`.

Comment: What did `git status` show you _before_ doing the erroenous `git add .` ?

Comment: On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/latest'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

Comment: Your `master` branch is tracking a remote branch called `latest`.  Does this sound correct to you?  Do you intend to be on the `master` branch?

Comment: Yes, my `master` branch is tracking a remote branch called `latest`. Regarding "Do you intend to be on the master branch?" Is this question about remote `master` branch? If so, I do not intend to be on the remote `master` branch, because I do not work with this branch - with this remote `master` branch works other people.

Comment: This strikes me as odd.  I think maybe you should be on a _local_ branch called `latest`, not on `master`.  Not sure if this will fix your problem.

Comment: Long time I work like this, having local `master` and do commits to `origin/latest` :) Will change it sometime later. The most interesting question how to find what files have changes?) The changes themself is not important, because they are small and can be reproduced, but I would like to know how to fix this case :)